# Add XML Attribute with namespace

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to add elements to an automatically generated XML file that I can then import back into the generator, but I'm running into an issue with some namespace attributes.

Here is what I'm trying to recreate:

```xml
<IP_Filter_Template_Guid dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```bsh
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $xmldoc)

$child1element = $xml.CreateElement($rapname)
$child1element.SetAttribute("name", $rapname)
$child1 = $xml.Root.Children.Microsoft_Internet_Authentication_Service.Children.RadiusProfiles.Children.AppendChild($child1element)

$child2element = $xml.CreateElement("Properties")
$child2 = $child1.AppendChild($child2element)

$child3element1 = $xml.CreateElement("IP_Filter_Template_Guid", $xmlns)
$child3element1.SetAttribute("dt", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes", "string")
$child3element1.SetAttribute("dt", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xmlns", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes")

$child3 = $child2.AppendChild($child3element1)

$child3element1.AppendChild($xml.CreateTextNode("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"))

$xml.Save("c:\xml.xml")
```

Here is the output I'm getting for the element:

```xml
<IP_Filter_Template_Guid d9p1:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string" xmlns:d9p1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xmlns">
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the new node as a plain XML node (no namespace manager needed):

```
$node = $xml.CreateElement('IP_Filter_Template_Guid')
```

Create a new attribute node with the desired namespace and assign a value to it:

```
$ns   = 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes'
$attr = $xml.CreateAttribute('dt', 'dt', $ns)
$attr.Value = 'string'
```

Add the attribute to the XML node using `SetAttributeNode()` (***not*** `SetAttribute()`!):

```
$node.SetAttributeNode($attr)
```

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> [xml]$xml = '<root/>'
PS C:\> $node = $xml.CreateElement('IP_Filter_Template_Guid')
PS C:\> $ns = 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes'
PS C:\> $attr = $xml.CreateAttribute('dt', 'dt', $ns)
PS C:\> $attr.Value = 'string'
PS C:\> $node.SetAttributeNode($attr) >$null
PS C:\> $node.OuterXml
<IP_Filter_Template_Guid dt:dt="string" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as you described, only it doesn't show the xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes in the xml document after I run $xml.save().

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how XML works, but the parent is <Root xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">

Comment: Then the namespace doesn't need to be declared again in a child node.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: my previous comment was referring to the resulting XML data structure. You still need to specify the namespace when creating the attribute node.